# SEMRush API ERROR 135 :: API REPORT TYPE DISABLED

Tags: api, keyword, keyword-search

I have code which is calling SEMRush API and it is working fine for a while, and then suddenly I stared getting 403 on API call with SEMRush error:

```
ERROR 135 :: API REPORT TYPE DISABLED
```

The API endpoint which I am calling is:

```
http://us.api.semrush.com/?action=report&type=phrase_this&key={xxxxxx}&export=api&export_columns=Ph,Nq,Cp,Co,Nr&phrase=sport
```

I cannot find anything about this error in their documentation.

Please does anyone know what this error means and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your API call to the newer method. According to their documentation the database is no longer a subdomain and rather a parameter.

So instead of `http://us.api.semrush.com/?action=report&type=phrase_this&key={xxxxxx}&export=api&export_columns=Ph,Nq,Cp,Co,Nr&phrase=sport`

Try `http://api.semrush.com/?action=report&type=phrase_this&key={xxxxxx}&export=api&export_columns=Ph,Nq,Cp,Co,Nr&phrase=sport&database=us`